# Generic way to compare class instance in Java

Tags: java, compare

I am looking for a generic way to implement this code snippet:

```
if (!(obj instanceof MyClass)) {
    return false;
}
```

Ideally I would like something like (So I don't have to hard-code MyClass everytime):

```
if (!(obj instanceof this.getClass())) {
    return false;
}
```

However, this example does not work.

Comment: What does "not work" look like?\

Comment: @duffymo It would generate a compile-time error. `instanceof` requires a type name, not a `Class` object or literal. This code is as erroneous as `(obj instanceof Integer.class)` instead of `(obj instanceof Integer)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do

```
this.getClass().isInstance(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
getClass() != obj.getClass()
```

However this will not match for subclasses only for excact class match.